# Deleting content on powerpoint using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a weekly presentation that I'm trying to automate. Each week I delete all of the previous weeks contents and paste in the new data using a macro in excel. However I cannot figure out how to delete all of the previous contents. Note: I do not want to delete the slides, just the pictures that are on the slides.

Edited: Below is the code I use in excel to paste in the new data each week. This code is for a single slide. Is it possible to add code to delete the previous weeks data before pasting in the new data?

```
Sub PasteAltSummaryToDeck()
'PURPOSE: Copy alt summary page and paste into weekly deck'

Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim shp As Object
Dim MySlideArray As Variant
Dim MyRangeArray As Variant
Dim x As Long

'Create an Instance of PowerPoint
  On Error Resume Next

'Is PowerPoint already opened?
  Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

'Clear the error between errors
  Err.Clear

'If PowerPoint is not already open then Exit
  If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "PowerPoint Presentation is not open, aborting."
    Exit Sub
  End If

'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
  If Err.Number = 429 Then
    MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
    Exit Sub
  End If

  On Error GoTo 0

'Make PowerPoint Visible and Active
  PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Activate

'Create a New Presentation
  Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation

'List of PPT Slides to Paste to
  MySlideArray = Array(11)

'List of Excel Ranges to Copy from
    MyRangeArray = Array(Sheet2.Range("F5:AS60"))

'Loop through Array data
  For x = LBound(MySlideArray) To UBound(MySlideArray)
    'Copy Excel Range
        MyRangeArray(x).Copy

'Paste to PowerPoint and position
  On Error Resume Next
    Set shp = myPresentation.Slides(MySlideArray(x)).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=2) 'Excel 2007-2010
    Set shp = PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange 'Excel 2013
  On Error GoTo 0

'Center Object
  With myPresentation.PageSetup
    shp.Left = (.SlideWidth \ 2) - (shp.Width \ 2)
    shp.Top = (.SlideHeight \ 2) - (shp.Height \ 2)
  End With

  Next x

   'Record the date & time of procedure execution
    Range("ExportAltSumToPPT").Value = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yy") & " - " & 
Format(TimeValue(Now), "hh:mm AM/PM")

'Transfer Complete
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
 ThisWorkbook.Activate
  MsgBox "Complete!"


End Sub
```

Comment: For each slide, reverse loop through all shapes and delete. [See the documentation for PPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shape.delete), which still applies to the Excel-VBA aspect as you would use the related references.

Comment: When I try that it tells me the object doesn't support this property or method..

Comment: Catalina, please use the [edit] link to include the explanation and code you originally included in an "Answer", then deleted, into the question. This is important (see the site guidelines for asking questions in the [help]) both for those trying to answer as well as people with a similar problem who might find the question and answer useful :-)

Comment: Updated it with the code!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this;

```
    Sub deletepics()

        'variables
        Dim slide As slide
        Dim y As Long

        'loop through slides backwards and with the slides shapes if they are pictures then delete
        For Each slide In ActivePresentation.Slides 
            For y = slide.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
                With slide.Shapes(y)
                    If .Type = msoPicture Then
                        .Delete
                    End If
                End With
            Next
        Next

    End Sub
```

EDIT:If you want to delete images on only slides 14 to 2 you can do this. Ignore my comments they were wrong. But the below code will work for you.

```
Sub deletepics()

    'variables
    Dim slide As slide
    Dim y As Long
    'loop through slides backwards and with the slides shapes if they are pictures then delete


For y = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count To 2 Step -1
    If y <> 14 Then
        Set sldTemp = ActivePresentation.Slides(y)
            For lngCount = sldTemp.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
                    With sldTemp.Shapes(lngCount)
                        If .Type = msoPicture Then
                            .Delete
                        End If
                    End With
            Next
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: It  gives me an error saying "user-define type not defined" ??

Comment: I've tested it on a powerpoint of mine that had pictures on each slide and it ran fine. 

Presumably you are running from a powerpoint vba module and not an excel?

Comment: "Dim slide As slide"

Comment: That would be why - this code is not for an excel module, you didnt stipulate in your original question that you wanted to do it from excel

Comment: That worked great! Follow up question- I have 21 slides but only want it to delete slides 2-14... How would I edit the code for this??

Comment: you could just change the line "slide.Shapes.Count To 1" to "14 To 2" :)

Comment: so I would put:          For y = slide.Shapes.Count To 14 To 2 Step -1" ?

Comment: @CatalinaRadu Did you want the deletion code embedded in yoru Excel-VBA code or are you going to use the PPT-VBA?

Comment: @Cyril I was originally trying to embedded it in my Excel-VBA but this PPT-VBA works! Would love to still figure out the Excel. I'm still messing with your code to see how I can get it to work for me

Comment: @CatalinaRadu the answer i provided does this in Excel-VBA.

Comment: @CatalinaRadu ignore my comments - i've added another bit of code on the bottom of my answer which will only delete images between 14 and 2.

Comment: @SpyingSphinx hmm that deletes all of the slides I need it to but also deletes slides 14-20...

Comment: @CatalinaRadu my bad.. i made a typpo (must be getting late) change it so it reads "If y < 14 Then" instead of If y <> 14 Then

Comment: YAY it worked great! Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: @CatalinaRadu your welcome - enjoy VBA. PS it gets very annoying at times as im sure you will find out :)

Answer (score 0):

For deleting the content of slides via Excel, you can utilize the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub remove_previous_shapes_in_PPT()
    Dim sl As PowerPoint.Slide, sl_cnt As Long, pr As Object, pr_name As String, ppt As Object
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Set ppt = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    Set pr = ppt.Presentations(1)
    sl_cnt = pr.Slides.Count
    For j = sl_cnt To 2 Step -1
        Set sl = pr.Slides(j)
        For i = sl.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
            sl.Shapes(i).Delete
        Next i
    Next j
End Sub
```

This utilizes looping through the count of slides and a nested loop of going through the shapes within the slide.  In my above code, I leave slide 1 alone (you can just change the loop for `j` to go to 1, not 2, if you want the first slide content removed).

Note the items labeled `as Object` versus those that are bound to PPT references.  I didn't go through the steps of utilizing your particular PPT, as I typically deal with `GetObject()` for the active PPT window, having only 1 presentation open.

Comment: It gives me an error here: "Dim sl As PowerPoint.Slide, "

Comment: @CatalinaRadu and you have PowerPoint references turned on for your module?

Comment: Yes I have them turned on!

Comment: @CatalinaRadu just to be certain, the references I have turned on for my module include: **1)**  Visual Basic for Applications, **2)** Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library, **3)** OLE Automation, **4)** Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library, and **5)** Microsoft PowerPoint 16.0 Object Library.

Comment: @CatalinaRadu please confirm you have all 5 turned on.  That will help narrow down the issue.

Comment: Ah you're right for some reason my powerpoint one was no longer checked! worked after that :) how would I use your code to only delete slides 2-14??

Comment: @CatalinaRadu the loop `For j = sl_cnt To 2 Step -1` would be changed to `For j = 14 To 2 Step -1`; additionally, you wouldn't need to define or use `sl_cnt` (slide count) and can remove the related items/lines.  If this resolves your issue, please mark as your answer.